# How to clear the SKU & URL Key fields when duplicating a product in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Is there a way to hook into the action of duplicating a product in Magento so that it would initially clear the SKU & URL Key fields to avoid duplicate product URLs with numbers on the end?

Comment: check this http://www.atwix.com/magento/duplicated-product-url-keys-in-community-edition/

Comment: You can create observer for 'catalog_model_product_duplicate' event and clear this values or do whatever You want with them.

Comment: I've managed to get an observer working when the product is duplicated. This works: `$newProduct = $observer->getEvent()->getNewProduct();
        
        $newProduct->setUrlKey("Hello");` but this doesn't work: `$newProduct->setUrlKey("");` Is there any way to clear the URL Key field?